# Ubuntu 20.04 destroyed Java/Mysql app performance

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, java

I'm working on a Java / MySQL app and test runs of batch processing were taking 3-4seconds on 18.04.

I made the upgrade to 20.04 and kept the same mysql conf file and now the same app is taking 1min and 45-47 seconds !!!

```
6.27user 0.41system 1:45.53elapsed 6%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 168724maxresident)k
0inputs+384outputs (0major+42056minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

I noticed with lscpu that the server is now running in min freq on average. I tried adding "acpi=ht" to /etc/default/grub to turn off power management but the processors is still running at low frequency.

```
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-15
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       2
NUMA node(s):                    2
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           44
Model name:                      Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5620  @ 2.40GHz
Stepping:                        2
Frequency boost:                 enabled
CPU MHz:                         1599.592
CPU max MHz:                     2401.0000
CPU min MHz:                     1600.0000
BogoMIPS:                        4799.75
Virtualization:                  VT-x
L1d cache:                       256 KiB
L1i cache:                       256 KiB
L2 cache:                        2 MiB
L3 cache:                        24 MiB
```

Is there a simple way to revert to 18.04 or are there known issues with 20.04 and mysql or java?

Comment: It's normal for the CPU to be at minimum frequency if the load is low, the CPU governor may have changed.  The problem isn't the clockspeed, 1600/2400 is a lot more than 3/105.